# React title changing based on domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 domains in my React project that works like, "develop.something.com" and "develop.somethingnew.com". Currently both the domains taking the index.html file's title. But, now I want to set the separate individual titles for both the domains via the array methods or via the other methods when they are appeared on the UI. How should I go about implementing this?

Comment: One way is use `process.env` and have a different `.env` file for each domain. See create-react-app docs for how to use

Answer (score 0):

Based on `window.location` object (which has the host name details) you can set the title

```
function buildTitle(href) {
  const titles = {
    "develop.something.com": "Some title",
    "develop.somethingnew.com": "New Title",
  };
  const key = Object.keys(titles).find((t) => href.includes(t));
  return key ? titles[key] : "Default title";
}

function updateTtile(title) {
  window.document.title = title;
}

// In the component
updateTitle(buildTitle(window.location.href));
```